# How to get value of UART register at raspberry pi 3?

Tags: c, raspberry-pi3, uart

I want to ask something about get value of registers for miniUART in raspberryPi3.
What I want to do is making serial transmitter without any libraries.

At first, I make program with "termios" and I checked it was working 
and I want to check what registers are changed when library functions of termios are conducted. But when I print the values, they are always 0. I can't find what is the problem...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 1024
#define BLOCK_SIZE 1024
#define GPIO_BASE 0x7E210000
#define PERI_BASE 0x7E000000
#define UART_BASE (PERI_BASE + 0x00215000)

static volatile unsigned int *IO, *IER, *LCR, *MCR, 
            *LSR, *MSR, *SCRATCH, *CNTL, *STAT, *BAUD, *UART;


void init_reg(int fd);
void print_reg();

int main(int argc, char** argv){
  int sfd = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY );
  if (sfd == -1){
      printf( " eno : %d\n", errno);
      printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
      return -1;
  }

  int fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC);
  if ( fd == -1){
      printf("Fail to open /dev/mem\n");
      return -1;
  }

  init_reg(fd);

  struct termios options;
  tcgetattr(sfd, &options);
  cfsetspeed(&options, B9600);
  print_reg();  
  cfmakeraw(&options);
  options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
  options.c_cflag |= CLOCAL;
  options.c_cflag |= CREAD;
  options.c_cc[VTIME] = 1;
  options.c_cc[VMIN] = 100;
  tcsetattr(sfd, TCSANOW, &options);
  print_reg();

  return 0;
}

void init_reg(int fd){
  UART = (unsigned int*)mmap(0, BLOCK_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, UART_BASE);

  IO = UART + 0x40;
  IER = UART + 0x44;
  LCR = UART + 0x4C;
  MCR = UART + 0x50;
  LSR = UART + 0x54;
  MSR = UART + 0x58;
  SCRATCH = UART + 0x5C;
  CNTL = UART + 0x60;
  STAT = UART + 0x64;
  BAUD = UART + 0x68;
}

void print_reg(){
    print_binary("IO", (*IO));
    print_binary("IER",(*IER));
    print_binary("LCR",(*LCR));
    print_binary("MCR",(*MCR));
    print_binary("LSR",(*LSR));
    print_binary("MSR",(*MSR));
    print_binary("CNTL",(*CNTL));
    print_binary("STAT",(*STAT));
    print_binary("BAUD",(*BAUD));
    print_binary("SCRATCH", (*SCRATCH));*/
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I can't find what is the problem..

The problem is that you're misusing the address returned by **mmap()**, which BTW you fail to validate.
The returned pointed is assigned to a pointer of type unsigned integer.

```
static volatile unsigned int ... *UART;
...
  UART = (unsigned int*)mmap(...);
```

You then try to access the contents of UART registers using (improper) pointer arithmetic, such as:

```
  IO = UART + 0x40;
```

Presumably 0x40 (and the other displacements you use) is a byte offset.

In a C expression of `<pointer> + <scaler>`, the `<scaler>` is taken to represent a quantity with the same size as the pointer type (e.g. `sizeof(unsigned int)`).
Only when the pointer is a byte pointer would the `<scaler>` represent a byte count.

So since `UART` is declared as a pointer to a 4-byte word, your pointer calculation in

```
IO = UART + 0x40;
```

is really equivalent to

```
IO = (unsigned int *)((unsigned char *)UART + (sizeof(unsigned int) * 0x40));
```

where `sizeof(unsigned int)` is 4 (bytes), and the offset applied is quadruple what you intended.

So instead of accessing the UART hardware registers, you're reading random (possibly non-existant) memory locations.  Such a coding error can result in a bus error when the location is actually invalid.

You could confirm these statements (or debug your code) by using **printf()**  to report the values of `UART`, `IO`, and other pointer variables.

---

Note, most of the termios settings only affect software states rather than UART registers, with baudrate, framing, and CRTSCTS (HW flow control) being the notable exceptions