# How to read a 64 bit register in Linux Kernel driver

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, powerpc

I want to read the value of a 64bit register in the Linux Kernel driver
I tried the below code, but I get 0 always.

```
    reg_addr = ioremap(0xffe602000, 0x20000); 
    if (!reg_addr) {
        printk(KERN_ALERT " ioremap failed \n");
    }else{
        printk(KERN_ALERT "  ioremap success reg_addr[0x%X]\n", reg_addr);
    }
```

the ioremap was successful in the above code.

after the ioremap, I call read as below:

```
    unsigned long long val;
    val = ioread64(reg_addr+0x300);
    printk(KERN_ALERT " ### REG READ returning [%lx] ###\n",val);
```

the above code prints

```
### REG READ returning [0] ###
```

I checked using Trace32, the value of register is not 0, the real value of the register is `0x00000000e506a904`.

did I miss something?

kernel version:

```
4.19.33 #12 SMP ppc64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: "*did I miss something?*" -- Yes.  Your pointer arithmetic is (probably) flawed.  You only post snippets of code;  you haven't described exactly what you're trying to do..  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53236883/how-to-get-value-of-uart-register-at-raspberry-pi-3/53255604#53255604  "*the ioremap was successful in the above code.*" -- That code has a bug too; i.e. there's a missing 'else' keyword.

Comment: As @sawdust suggests, `ioread64(reg_addr+0x300)` is probably wrong and you want `ioread64(reg_addr + (0x300 / sizeof(u64)))` instead.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I have the `else` keyword in my original code,  I missed else while copying the code here. I modified the code now.

Comment: Please show the declaration of `reg_addr`. If it is declared as `void __iomem *reg_addr;` or `char __iomem *reg_addr;` then `reg_addr+0x300` should point to byte offset 0x300 from the remapped address.

Comment: Also, you should replace `%lx` with `%llx` to print the `unsigned long long` value. (`unsigned long long` should be the same size as `unsigned long` for a 64-bit kernel, so it doesn't matter too much, but it does prevent a compiler warning.)